# SQL Server Object Explorer separates Azure SQL databases that are in one Azure SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In Azure, I have several SQL databases connected to one SQL server.  When I look in the SQL server object explorer in Visual Studio, they are separated unlike the view of my on-premise SQL server.

All queries and connections work as expected but this is more of just a thorn in my side.  Is there a way to combine these.  The image may display better.  I would like the 3 azure databases (red) to look the green.

[image: SQL Explorer]

[image: Resource Visualizer]

Comment: There's no `one Azure SQL Server`. In Azure SQL, all databases are independent and more importantly, independently billed. Having multiple small Azure SQL databases is an expensive idea.

Comment: We are on low pricing models for now but 1 database needs to be separate.  Otherwise, would you recommend 1 database with a hundred tables or something like elastic pools?

Comment: Please consider elastic pools. Specially if the application is multi-tenant or the demand of resources is unpredictable. Take a look at the Elastic Client Library.

Comment: 100 tables isn't a lot. You can use schemas to group, organize tables and use separate permissions in the same database. For multi-tenancy, separate databases offer better isolation

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the comment, you can use a standard Azure SQL elastic pool to achieve the same.
**Elastic Pool:**

- Simple,Cost Effective solution for managing and scaling multiple databases.
- Resource allocation service used to scale and manage the perfomance and manage the performace and cost.
- It allows you to purchase resources for the group.

***Note:
Elastic pools are ideally suited, when you have several SQL databases that have a low average utilization, but infrequent, high utilization.***

**Pool Size:**

- Recomended that the combined resources you would need for individual database to meet the capacity spikes is more than 1.5 times the capacity required for the elastic pool, then pool will be cost effective.
- Depending on the performace tier we can add up to 100 (or) 500 databases to single pool.

Below are the steps how you can add databases to SQL elastic pool:
[image]
in the above image Sports DEV and Test are databases and I have sql server.
Create a resource SQL ELASTIC POOL in your Resource group with server name.

[image]

- navigate to the configure tab . And add databases then click save .

[image]
I have added my 2 databases in SQL elastic sql pool and they listed in sql pool.
[image]
[image]

Below are the Steps how you can manage SQL elastic Pool.

- Adjust elastic pool settings
- [Storage sizes and compute sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-dtu-elastic-pools?view=azuresql-db)
- [Manage elastic pools in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-manage?view=azuresql-db)

**Adjust elastic Pool Settings:**
[image]

- You can choose DTU based(or) V-core based pricing model.

[Compare vCore and DTU-based purchasing models of Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/purchasing-models?view=azuresql-db)

**Adjust database settings:**

- This can be done **Per Database**
- Here we can change the MIN and MAX DTU's for particular database.

[image]

**Add new database in the pool:**
Incase you want add new database you have to just provide the name of the database.
Go to the Overview and create database.
[image]
[image]
**Connecting the SQL elastic pool in SSMS:**
[image]

Comment: Your final picture is exactly what I want.  With my low tier databases, the pool ends up costing more but when I scale up, I will follow this.  Thanks.  I will leave open if there are other solutions.